# What is the correct procedure to replace MDM with LightDM on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, lightdm, display-manager, mdm

OS: Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit.

I almost got a heart attack, after reboot preceding this; in an important VM:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

... I chose LightDM as the default DM ...

```
sudo apt-get purge mdm
```

I underestimated it as after reboot the LightDM failed to start. What's more I could not get to Virtual Console, there was just an underscore blinking. After yet another reboot, the same behavior.

I fixed that in a while over SSH by purging LightDM and installing MDM back.

What is the correct procedure to replace MDM with LightDM on Linux Mint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [official statement](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3306):

```
sudo apt-get install slick-greeter lightdm lightdm-settings apparmor
```

Did not yet get me to the result.

I had to create a file:

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

with contents:

```
[Seat:*]
allow-guest=false
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be done with *dpkg-reconfigure*:

`$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

or

`$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm`

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/dpkg-reconfigure.8.html