# Execute script prior to cinnamon logout (unsing MDM or other display manager)

Tags: shell-script, cinnamon, session, logout, mdm

I'm using cinnamon as desktop environment on my Linux Mint system.

I want to automate a backup using **unison**:

Unison shall be executed *prior* to each logout off my session. So I was looking for a solution to execute unison every time I use the shutdown button *from the cinnamon menu*.

However, I was not able to find a hook that allows me to intercept the shutdown.

I also read about `session-cleanup-script` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. However, this does not seem to apply to my system: I seem to use the MDM Display Manager. I've been looking for hooks there.

I also tried to override `/usr/bin/cinnamon-session-quit`, but this seems not to be called from the shutdown menu.

Comment: just a note `mdm` had been deprecated since Mint 18

Comment: I guess, it is an artefact of an upgraded older installation. What is the new default DM?

Comment: As of Mint 18 the default and recommended is LightDM.

Comment: Read on how to switch to it in my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408673/126755

Comment: I see no need to switch the default DM, as long as it does not help solve my genuine problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to LightDM as I was suggesting, then it should be simple.

Set the following parameter in the config file:

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

> ```
> session-cleanup-script = Script to run when quitting a user session (runs as root)
> ```

Comment: Hm, unfortunately I cannot test if this works: 
I tried to switch to LigthDM, but it crashes upon Login (without having edited the aforementioned file) - I guess its a problem with my graphics driver, but that's another story...

Comment: Did you follow my [instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408673/126755) ?

Comment: Did you read my comment? I can't test your instructions, as ligthdm doesn't work for me. However, i followed the instructions regarding the lightdm installation.